Optimising Node Geomoetry for Fractal Castles
This question is based on that little program: Castles Made of Castles
Note: you can type t when playing to see the original geometry.
I have successfully been able to create a first castle on Blender based on that castle geometry

But I am running into trouble when trying a more complex geometry, like this second castle and when applying iteration 4 it crashes.
You can find my blender file here at interation 3.
A) How can I optimise the geometry node to help with the calculation?
B) I cannot use the Boolean Modifier or Mesh Boolean as it takes forever to merge the blocks. I have used the Merge by distance Node that helps but does an incomplete job (you can see artefacts on the castle facade). I can transform into mesh and then in the sculpt mode remesh, but it is not optimal. Is there another solution to merge the blocks?
